# How to tell unit ms test to pick up CSV file from a subfolder and not root?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, testing

I have written a unit test that uses a CSV file to read in data using the "DataSource" and "DeploymentItem" Attributes pointing to a csv file in a subfolder.  However, when initially building the project the files are deployed in two different locations, one in the root and the other in the subfolder. When I then later change the CSV file with different data and save and re-build the project (having the CSV property "Copy to Output" set to "Copy always", just to make sure), it copies the changes to the correct output subfolder but not the root.  This is what I would expect but the problem is, that when running the tests, it still reads in old data because it picks the CSV file up from the root and not the subfolder.  So each time I have to go to the output folder and copy the CSV file from the subfolder into the root folder for the test to pick up the changes.

Does anybody know how to fix this so the test looks in the subfolder to pick up the CSV file and not the root?

```
[TestMethod()]
[DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.CSV", @"|DataDirectory|\\Data\MyData.csv", "MyData#csv", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
[DeploymentItem("MyApp\\MyTest\\MyTests.Tests\\Data\\MyData.csv")]
```

Comment: I just realised I'm barking up the wrong tree. The problem is not with VS but with Resharper.  Running the unit tests using Visual Studio's own test runner works fine, it's when running them using the Resharper test runner that this problem occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a TestSettings.settings file to your solution by selecting the solution and then clicking `New...` and then selecting `TestSettings`.  if you double click that fie it will give you a dialog with some options, one of those is `Deployment`. If you enable that, you can add files and directories that get deployed to your test running directory.

This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256991.aspx) explains it a bit better.

Comment: Thanks, this answers the question but I realised today that I'm using Resharper in VS for testing and it didn't occur to me until now that it was behaving differently from the VS test runner.

Comment: I'm going to mark this one as answered and have posted a new question to bark at the right tree this time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23426681/how-to-tell-resharper-to-pick-up-csv-files-for-unit-tests-from-the-correct-subfo